# Where can I find an applet that requires Java 6?

Tags: java, applet, java-6

I currently have Java 5 installed on Windows. I'm trying to test the way the new Java Kernal installs when my Firefox browser comes across an applet requiring Java 6.  Unfortunately the applets I try fail to run or just run the Java 5 JVM.  I have tried:

1. http://jdk6.dev.java.net/plugin2/
2. http://www.psynixis.com/test/HelloJava6Applet.html
3. http://bfo.co.uk/products/pdf/viewer.jsp

Can anyone point me to other applets that require Java 6?

Answer (score 2):

Try

http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp?detect=jre&try=1

They use an applet in the background to determine the version of Java you are running.

**Update:** it will tell you the version you are running in the URL:

http://www.java.com/en/download/dt_verify.jsp?plugin=false&latest=false&**users_jre=1.5.0**

Answer (score 0):

It's very rare to see an Applet that requires 1.6.  After all, I don't think any of the things an applet uses require Java 6.

A quicker way to see would be to uninstall Java 5, then try to run an applet... you'll probably be prompted to download Java 6u13.